# What is the antonym of "short of"?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases, antonyms

We often use "short of" as in

> We are short of cash

meaning we do not have enough cash. I wonder what is the antonym of "short of", which means "having too much of".

Actually, I expect it to have a similar structure like "* of"?

Since the antonym of "short" is "tall/long", can we say "tall of" or "long of"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We have **a surplus of** cash

Or you can say

> We have **surplus** cash

It is a **[noun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/surplus)**, and can also be used as an adjective, which means

> something that remains above what is used or needed.

And it also means

> an amount of assets in excess of what is requisite to meet liabilities.

That does fit the situation in this question. Someone might argue that surplus does not really mean *abundance of* as might be expected by the OP but there is a fine difference to note here in what OP has typed and the situation that OP has presented.

*Short of* does not mean having *very little*, it means closer to the target but a little less. Hence the antonym for that situation would be something that expresses the fact that it is a little more than what is needed, which **surplus** explains well. *Abundance of* or *Plenty of* change the expression.

Comment: Note: In your example here, _surplus_ is not a noun, but an adjective (or more precisely, a noun adjunct). As a true noun, it would be, “We have _a_ surplus _of_ cash”.

Answer (score 4):

In ordinary conversation, the opposite of "short of" is "plenty of" or "too much".  For example:

> I **am short of** cash.  I'd better stop at the ATM on the way home.
>
> I **have plenty of** cash.  I'll wait a few days before stopping at the ATM.
>
> I **have too much** cash.  I should deposit some money into my bank account.

Answer (score 3):

**an abundance of**.

> A *large quantity of something*: the tropical island boasts an
>   abundance of wildlife

[Source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abundance#abundance__2)

In your example, you could say "We have an abundance of cash."

Answer (score -1):

In the context of short-term demands for assets (such as cash, stocks, bonds, and inventory, the natural opposites are:

- "short on" (or "short of")
- "long on"

For example:

> He is house-rich, but cash-poor.
> He has a nice house, but he is always short of cash.
>
> My bridge hand was really weird.  I had ten spades, and just one heart, one diamond, and one club.
> I was long on spades, and short on hearts, diamonds, and clubs.

In securities markets (such as the stock market), these phrases are usually abbreviated to:

- "short"
- "long"

For example:

> Al Abrams runs the Breakout Fund.  He is long GM.  He is short Ford.

This means that Al's fund owns stock in General Motors (GM).  He has borrowed Ford Motor Company stock -- and sold more than he actually owns.  If Al had to settle all of his positions, he would have plenty of shares of GM to sell.  But he would not have enough Ford stock to satisfy his creditors -- he would need to buy some in order to settle his debts.  He is betting that GM's stock will go up more than Ford's stock will.

Comment: I think it's important to note that while "short on" is a common phrase, "long on" remains just a finance term. Most people who don't know the phrase from finance would probably understand it if you said "I'm long on cash" after some thought, but it's not in most people's lexicon.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi: Disagree. "short on facts, but long on love" http://www.latimes.com/home/la-hm-0926-erskine-20150926-column.html , "short on economic benefits, long on risk" http://www.latimes.com/nation/la-na-keystone-pipeline-decision-20151106-story.html , "short on sight, long on sounds" http://www.democratandchronicle.com/story/lifestyle/music/2015/11/09/musician-donald-orton/75439614/ , "Long on Style, Short on Substance" http://www.breitbart.com/big-government/2015/10/18/marco-rubio-campaign-long-style-short-substance/ . Though these are all "long on X, short on Y" constructions.

Comment: All this means is that "short on X, long on Y" is an idiom. Suggesting to learners that the phrase "long on", in a vaccum, is as anywhere common as "short on" is misleading. I think its important we note the perceived tone/diction of phrases.

Comment: @Eric, that is just a turn of phrase though. A formula for a turn of phrase doesn't make something common usage. In fact for a turn of phrase to be considered clever, it usually has to be explicitly uncommon usage.